# Issue With uib datepicker popup, showing top part only

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, uib

I copied code from a template but the uib-datepicker popup only showing partially. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Add `datepicker-append-to-body="true"` in html

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepickerPopup

Comment: after added this to inpit, it is not even poped up

Comment: thanks - this worked for me! Although, my issue was a bit different. The control wasn't top-most. It acted as if it was transparent as controls behind it took focus.